# elasticsearch not unable to know the cluster's nodes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have a a cluster of 4 nodes, 2 masters and 2 slaves all running on dockers.

The config of the master is below:

```
network:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  publish_host: myIP

http:
  port: 9201

transport.tcp.port: 9301

path:
  logs: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Authorization, Content-Length

cluster.name: lpfrlogsconcentration

node:
  name: "node-1"
  master: true
  data: false
  ingest: true

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
  - myIP:9301
  - myIP:9302
  - myIP:9303
  - myIP:9304
```

And for the slaves, it is:

```
 network:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  publish_host: myIP

http:
  port: 9203

transport.tcp.port: 9303

path:
  logs: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2


http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Authorization, Content-Length

cluster.name: lpfrlogsconcentration

node:
  name: "node-3"
  master: false
  data: true
  ingest: true

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:

  - myIP:9301
  - myIP:9302
  - myIP:9303
  - myIP:9304
```

But when I run the dockers, I get on the nodes 1 & 2 (the masters) this error :

```
[2018-06-14T08:41:02,744][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] 
[node-1] failed to send join request to master 
[{node-2}{UNxVYf5mQUSUV3Z9h6c7Pw}{4xJAijDHTfCNfdjyUDLvtQ}{221.128.56.131}{221.128.56.131:9302}], 
reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-2][172.17.0.2:9302][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; 
nested: NotMasterException[Node [{node-2}{UNxVYf5mQUSUV3Z9h6c7Pw}{4xJAijDHTfCNfdjyUDLvtQ}
{221.128.56.131}{221.128.56.131:9302}] not master for join request]; ],
tried [3] times
```

Can you help me debug this?

Comment: Are you using the first config file for both of the master nodes?

Comment: with data: true and different ports of course